# Looking to identify a book series about a human female sent to kill an alien to save her daughter

Tags: story-identification

There is this book I remember reading but cant remember the name of it. Its in a series about a human female sent to kill this male alien to save her daughter but falls in love with him instead. Could anyone help me with the name of the title and or series? I have tried looking for it at public libraries and searching the internet but have come up with nothing.

Comment: Hi and welcome, take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to get in some more details such as when you read it. Any other details, etc.